# Create GUID and Register it into the Registry

Tags: c++

I tried to create an GUID with CoCreateGuid and I want to add this guid into the registry using RegSetValueEx.

I'm not a so good coder, but i'm learning it. I tried some ways, but always I get any error.
So I want to ask the people here if they can help me to solve this problem, to register a guid into a key in the Registry.
I will be very thanksfull if some one can solve this puzzle.
I looked into the WWW but i didn't found anything there, that looks like an fix.

Before I forget it, i'm using "Microsoft Visual Studio .Net 2003" version 7.1.3088, I need to use this old version because the Dll was create 2004/2005. (I know this has not so much to do with my problem)

My last try was this one(If someone has a another way to register an created guid to a key in the Registry than I will be thanksfull too :-) ):

```
GUID guid;
    unsigned char* StringUuid;
    if (CoCreateGuid(&guid) == S_OK){
        if (UuidToString(&guid, &StringUuid) == RPC_S_OK){
            RpcStringFree(&StringUuid) ;
        }
        else{
            FILE *openlog=fopen("log.txt","a"); //Add an error message
            if(openlog)
            {
                fprintf(openlog, "Error 2!");
            }
            fprintf(openlog,"\n");
            fclose(openlog);
        }
    }
    else{
            FILE *openlog=fopen("log.txt","a"); //Add an error message
            if(openlog)
            {
                fprintf(openlog, "Error 1!");
            }
            fprintf(openlog,"\n");
            fclose(openlog);
    }

    HKEY key;
    DWORD dwDisposition;
    if(RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
        TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Test"), 
        0, 
        NULL, 
        0, 
        KEY_WRITE, 
        NULL, 
        &key, 
        &dwDisposition) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        long SetComm = RegSetValueEx(key, "test_one", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)StringUuid, strlen(StringUuid));
        if(SetComm == ERROR_SUCCESS){
            FILE *openlog=fopen("log.txt","a"); //Add positive message into file
            if(openlog)
            {
                fprintf(openlog, "[Successfully]: Writed!");
            }
            fprintf(openlog,"\n");
            fclose(openlog);
        }else{
            FILE *openlog=fopen("log.txt","a"); //Add failed message into file
            if(openlog)
            {
                fprintf(openlog, "[Successfully]: Error to Write!");
            }
            fprintf(openlog,"\n");
            fclose(openlog);
        }
        RegCloseKey(key);
    }
```

Comment: Use GetLastError() to see why it is failing.  May need to run as admin.

Comment: The error on Debuging the DLL is: error C2664: 'strlen' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned char *' to 'const char *'

Comment: when you say "register" what exactly do mean? in principle writing to the registry is done in one way or if your program is some kind of COM object/server then you let VS do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: That what I exactly mean, is that the Guid is registered on a key. But with an pic its easier to explain: [RegistryEntry](http://176.57.129.97/farcry/download/images/Register.GIF), Test_Test is the key, and Register Guid Here is the GUID who the system automaticaly creates, and so, register into the Registry.

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html